# SQL Query - Return all values up to particular value

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I am trying to execute a SQL query which first sorts the data with the most recent one in row 1, and then returns all entries from row 1 up to an entry with a particular ID. The purpose of this is to load content to a mobile app, and when the user refreshes the content, only the content which is newer than the newest one he has already loaded is returned. So far I came up with this :

```
    $all_feed_posts = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * 
      FROM feed_img_vid 
      WHERE city_geo_name_id = '$geo_name_id' 
      ORDER BY timestamp DESC 
      LIMIT WHERE feed_instance_id = $offset");
```

however I'm not sure if the limit keyword is the right one to use here.

Comment: You should RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html   `limit` is completely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have last id been read in `$offset` var then you can just add `AND` into your clause.

I guess all newer records should have `feed_instance_id > $offset`:

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM feed_img_vid 
  WHERE city_geo_name_id = '$geo_name_id' 
     AND feed_instance_id > $offset
  ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

LIMIT only get a number of rows and offset use HAVING AND < or > or =

```
     $all_feed_posts = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM feed_img_vid WHERE
 city_geo_name_id = '$geo_name_id' 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC HAVING feed_instance_id < $offset");
```

Comment: It gives me a syntax error.... `feed_instance_id` is a `Varchar`. its just a primary key representing the individual item

Answer (score 0):

You can try this bro.

```
$limit = $offset; // or whatever upto you want to pluck
$all_feed_posts = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM feed_img_vid WHERE city_geo_name_id = '$geo_name_id' ORDER BY timestamp DESC HAVING feed_instance_id <= $limit");
```

of course you can use $offset directly

## happyCoding